# How to generate sql from template and param placeholder with JOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I get the sql template like this with jOOQ 3.11.11.

```java
DSLContext context = new DefaultDSLContext(conf);
Query query = context.select().from("table1").where(DSL.field("report_date").eq(DSL.param("bizdate")));
String sqlTemp = context.renderNamedParams(query);
```

I store the plain sql template.

```sql
select * from table1 where report_date = :bizdate
```

The param 'bizdate' is decided by realtime query.
So. How to generate the real sql

```sql
select * from table1 where report_date = '20190801'
```

with the stored sql template string and the realtime input date '20190801'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate sql from template with order by parameter using jOOQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57591155/how-to-generate-sql-from-template-with-order-by-parameter-using-jooq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
context.resultQuery(sqlTemp, DSL.param("bizdate", "20190801")).fetch();
```

See [`DSLContext.resultQuery(String, QueryPart...)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#resultQuery-java.lang.String-org.jooq.QueryPart...-)

Comment: Got it! There is another problem. I have updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: @JerryChou, thanks for your update. The way Stack Overflow works, that update is really a new question. For future visitors of this question, it may be confusing to follow the edits. Would you mind reverting the edit and ask a new question instead? I'll be very happy to answer that as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57591155/how-to-generate-sql-from-template-with-order-by-parameter-using-jooq, @LukasEder