# How to generate SQL from template with order by parameter using jOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I generate the SQL template like this with jOOQ 3.11.11.

```java
DSLContext context = new DefaultDSLContext(conf);
Query query = context.select()
    .from("table1")
    .where(DSL.field("report_date").eq(DSL.param("bizdate")))
    .orderBy(DSL.param("sort"));
String sqlTemp = context.renderNamedParams(query);
```

SQL template:

```sql
select * 
from table1 
where report_date = :bizdate 
order by :sort
```

The SQL template is stored and the params are decided at realtime query condition.

```java
ResultQuery resultQuery = context.resultQuery(sqlTemp, DSL.param("bizdate", "20190801"), DSL.param("sort", "id desc"));
```

The realtime SQL:

```sql
select * 
from table1 
where report_date = '20190801' 
order by 'id desc'
```

There is something wrong with the order by clause.

So. How to replace the order by param *sort* with *"id desc"* or *"name asc"* and eliminate the quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DSL.param()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#param-java.lang.String-T-) creates a bind variable, which is generated as `?` in SQL, or `:bizdate` if you choose to use named parameters, or `'20190801'` if you choose to inline the bind variables. [More about bind variables can be seen here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/).

You cannot use `DSL.param()` to generate column references or keywords. A column expression (e.g. a reference) is described in the jOOQ expression tree by the [`Field`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html) type. Keywords are described by the [`Keyword`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Keyword.html) type, but you probably do not want to go this low level. Instead you want to handle some of the logic in your query expression. For example:

```java
String sortField = "id";
SortOrder sortOrder = SortOrder.ASC;

Query query = context.select()
    .from("table1")
    .where(DSL.field("report_date").eq(DSL.param("bizdate")))
    .orderBy(DSL.field(sortField).sort(sortOrder));
```

The mistake you're making is to think that you can use a single SQL template for all sorts of different dynamic SQL queries, but what if you're dynamically adding another predicate? Or another join? Or another column? You'd have to build a different jOOQ expression tree anyway. Just like here. You could store two SQL strings (one for each sort order), and repeat that for each sort column.

But, instead of pre-generating a single SQL string, I recommend you extract a function that takes the input parameters and generates the query every time afresh, e.g.:

```java
ResultQuery<?> query(String bizDate, Field<?> sortField, SortOrder sortOrder) {
    return context.selectFrom("table1")
                  .where(field("report_date").eq(bizDate))
                  .orderBy(sortField.sort(sortOrder));
}
```

Here is some further reading about using jOOQ for dynamic SQL:

- https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dynamic-sql
- https://blog.jooq.org/2017/01/16/a-functional-programming-approach-to-dynamic-sql-with-jooq

Comment: I just got the plain sql. Can I parse the plain sql to Select Object, then append the order by clause and limit offset clause?

Comment: @JerryChou: That's another, quite different question :) Yes, you can, but I'll explain in a different question...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57601416/how-to-modify-plain-text-sql-with-jooq-such-as-appending-order-by-limit-offset-c, @ LukasEder