# How to modify plain sql text with jOOQ such as appending order-by/limit-offset clause or changing where condition value?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I build a sql template with named params using jOOQ 3.11.11.

```sql
select * from table1 where report_date = :bizdate
```

Then I stored the sql template text. For each query, I will replace the param *bizdate* with user input.
[how to generate sql from template and param placeholder with JOOQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57588198/how-to-generate-sql-from-template-and-param-placeholder-with-jooq)
the realtime sql like this:

```sql
select * from table1 where report_date = '20190801'
```

It works well. But there is another question. I want to append an order-by clause and a limit-offset clause to the sql. The order by field is dynamic and decided by user input as well as the limit offset param. 
The realtime sql like this:

```sql
select * from table1 where report_date = '20190801' order by id desc limit 0,10
```

or

```sql
select * from table1 where report_date = '20190801' order by name asc limit 5,20
```

How to generate the sql from the template and realtime input with jOOQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57592174/1732086) to the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57591155/1732086) I think it would be best if you didn't run dynamic SQL queries based on an SQL string, but rather built a new query using the jOOQ API each time. Then the `LIMIT` clause is also trivial to add:

```java
ResultQuery<?> query(String bizDate, Field<?> sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, int limitOffset, int limitRows) {
    return context.selectFrom("table1")
                  .where(field("report_date").eq(bizDate))
                  .orderBy(sortField.sort(sortOrder)
                  .limit(limitOffset, limitRows));
}
```

If you do work with an SQL string you can again use the same pattern as before:

```java
    ResultQuery resultQuery = context.resultQuery(
        sqlTemp,
        DSL.param("bizdate", "20190801"),
        DSL.field(sortField).sort(sortOrder),
        DSL.param("limit", limitOffset),
        DSL.param("rows", limitRows));
```

As another option you could maybe also use Java serialization to [serialize your query](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/sql-building/queryparts/serializability/) instead of storing it as a plain String.